# How to check if a digit is in a number [MYSQL]

Tags: mysql

I have a small Problem. I'm very new to MYSQL and I want to check if a specific digit/number is in another number. A small example:

(In this example, it should select everything from Table 1 that has a number that is contained in the value of Table 2)

Table 1:

```
id  value
1   3
2   4
3   1
4   2
```

Table 2:

```
id2 values
1   13
```

Result:

Table 1

```
id value
1  3 
3  1
```

(Because id 1 and 3 have the value 3 and 1, which is contained in the number 13)

I hope someone could help me. It would also be possible if there was another format for the 13, like "1,3" if that would be easier. I'm sorry for my bad English. I speak German natively.

Comment: If the `'13'` represents a `'1'` and a `'3'`, but not the numeric value `13`, then storing them in a single value is wrong, even storing them as comma separated strings is wrong; always store discrete values separately, not combined as strings. The `1` and the `3` should either be on different rows or in different columns. Then the SQL becomes trivial; because then you're using SQL the way it's designed.

Comment: That's what i also thought. But the problem that I have is, that the value 13 is user specific. Then I would create multiple rows with the same user id or create infinite columns. So it has to be stored like that. Isn't there any possibility to do it?

Comment: so if someone enters in table2 as value `1234` you want to select all rows from table 1?

Comment: Yes. That's what i want. And if i enter 14 it should only display id 2 and 3

Comment: @silvinator There is no problem with using multiple rows in the way you describe. In fact, it's standard practice in link tables; anything that associates one entity (user) to multiple entities (your value) is typically done in this way. There are anti-patterns that do this the way you prefer, but they incur performance and maintenance penalties, so I personally refuse to teach such bad practices. *(Stop fighting the normalised structure inherent to SQL, learn it, embrace it, and understand it. Believing you know better will only lead to pain and difficulty.)*

Comment: So If i use a number like 123456789 i should create a column for each of these values? And if i have another value like 123 the other columns should stay empty? And what is if i would add values like 10 and would continue with that. So should i create all the rows for that? Would a split maybe be usefull to put all the values in a dummy table?

Comment: Multiple ***rows***, not columns. If `123456789` is an arbitrary list of 9 digits/characters, create 9 rows associated to that user's id. If another user specifies `123`, create 3 rows for that user. *(Look up adjacency lists, or link tables, with respect to relational databases.)*

Comment: The problem with rows is, that i have 2 of these values in 1 table. So value1 = 123 and value2 = 12. So there would be "2" table 2.

Comment: No, just add a column for the value id; `user_id, value_id, digit` = `1,1,1`, `1,1,2`, `1,1,3` would then specify that user 1's value 1 is made of digits `1`,`2`,`3`. Then you can have more rows for the same user but with a different `value_id`, for example `1,2,1`, `1,2,2` stores user 1's value 2 as the digits `1`,`2` *(Which can then accommodate an infinite number of users, each with an infinite number of values, each with an infinite number of digits. For this, look up normalisation, with respect to relational databases.)*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239692/discussion-between-silvinator-and-matbailie).

Comment: So it would look like this?:

id has the values 1, 1, 1 and v1 1,1,2 and v2 1,2,3 (just in rows, while id, v1 and v2 are the columns)

Comment: No, three rows for user1 value1 (one row for each digit, of which there are three digits), and two completely separate rows for user1 value2 (because it has two digits).  Just like in demonstrated in my previous comment; `user_id, value_id, digit` : `1,1,1`,`1,1,2`,`1,1,3` for user1 value1 = digits `1,2,3`, and then `1,2,1`,`1,2,2` for user1 value2 = digits `1,2`

Comment: Oh now i think i get it. Sorry for that. 3 Rows, while 1 row is the id, 1 row which value it would be (1 for value1 and 2 for value2) and the last row for the value. Thanks ^^

Comment: The first column is called `user_id`; if it has a `1` in it, it's for user1. The second column is called `value_id`; if it has a `2` in it, it's value2. The last column is called `digit`, and there is one row per digit.  So the row `1,2,1` says that user1's value2 contains a `1`. Another row `1,2,2` would independently state that user1's value2 contains a `2`. These are explicitly differentiated from user1's other values because the column `value_id` explicitly tells you which value the row relates to.  `1,1,9` for example, being user1 again, but now value1 (with a digit of 9), and not value2

Comment: Thanks. That is really helpful. I've got thought that I should not use the same value multiple times in a table (means 3 times user_id 1 is bad). Thats why i put the values in the same row ^^

Comment: I'm ending this conversation. You clearly are not going to look up `normalisation`, `adjacency list`, or `link table`. I don't see why I should spoon feed you when you're clearly not willing to help yourself. (I don't expect you to already know this stuff, but I do expect you to educate yourself when given the topics you will benefit from.)